# Save updated values to database and show them in html table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a table like the following:

```
    <script>
    $("#edit").hide(); // Hide the edit table first

    $("#update").click(function() {
            $("#edit").toggle();
            $("#shown").toggle();
            // If we are going from edit table to shown table

            if($("#shown").is(":visible")) {

                var vouchertype = $('input[name="vouchertype[]"]').map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
var mode= $('select[name="mode[]"]').map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();

                // Then add it to the shown table
         var baseurl='<?php echo base_url()."index.php/account/insert_voucher";?>';

                    $.ajax({

                            type: "POST",
                            url: baseurl,
                            data: $('#edit *').serialize() ,
                            cache: false,
                            success: function(html) {

                                alert(html);

                            }
                        });

                $(this).val("Edit");
            }
            else $(this).val("Update");
        });
</script>

  <table width="62%" height="70" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tbl_grid" id="shown">
              <?php if(count($voucher_info) > 0 ){ ?>
                      <tr class="bgcolor_02">
                        <td width="22%" height="25" align="center" class="admin" >S.no</td>
                        <td width="37%" align="center"  class="admin">Voucher Type</td>
                        <td width="37%" align="center"  class="admin">Voucher Mode</td>
                      </tr>
                      <?php 
                                            $rownum = 1;    
                                            foreach ($voucher_info as $eachrecord){
                                                    $zibracolor = ($rownum%2==0)?"even":"odd";
                                    ?>
                      <tr align="center"  class="narmal">
                        <td height="25"><?php echo $eachrecord->voucher_id; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $eachrecord->voucher_type; ?></td>
                             <td><?php echo ucwords($eachrecord->voucher_mode); ?></td>                         
                      </tr>
  <?php   } 
                    }                       
                    else {
                           echo "<tr class='bgcolor_02'>";
                           echo "<td align='center'><strong>No records found</strong></td>";
                           echo "</tr>";
                    } 
                  ?>


                 </table>

                <table width="62%" height="70" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
                 id="edit">             
                   <?php if(count($voucher_info) > 0 ){ ?>
                      <tr class="bgcolor_02">

                          <td width="27%" align="center"   class="admin" >S.no</td>
                        <td width="37%" align="center"   class="admin" >Voucher Type</td>
                        <td width="47%" align="center"   class="admin" >Voucher Mode</td>

                        <!--  <td width="41%" align="center" class="narmal">&nbsp;<strong>Actions</strong></td>-->

                      </tr>
                      <?php 
                                            $rownum = 1;    
                                            foreach ($voucher_info as $eachrecord){
                                                    $zibracolor = ($rownum%2==0)?"even":"odd";
                                    ?>
                      <tr align="center"  class="narmal">
                        <td height="25"><?php echo $eachrecord->voucher_id ; ?><input type="hidden" name="voucher_id[]" value="<?php echo $eachrecord->voucher_id; ?>" /></td>
                        <td><input name="vouchertype[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $eachrecord->voucher_type; ?>" /></td>    
                        <td><select name="mode[]" >
                        <option value="paidin" <?php if($eachrecord->voucher_mode=='paidin') { ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?>>Paid In</option>
                        <option value="paidout" <?php if($eachrecord->voucher_mode=='paidout') { ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?>>Paid Out</option>
                        </select></td>                  
                      </tr>
                      <?php   } }                   
                    else {
                           echo "<tr class='bgcolor_02'>";
                           echo "<td align='center'><strong>No records found</strong></td>";
                           echo "</tr>";
                    } 
                  ?>

                  </table>
                  </td>
                  </tr>
                 <input id="update" type="submit" name="submit" value="Edit"/
```

In first table I am displaying values from database. But when user click on edit button below the table, Then that table values should be editable for user. I have succeeded in making editable fields  but  again when user click on submit then updated values are not displaying in first table. I know it's possible with jQuery or JavaScript. When I `alert(newsales)`, the alert is undefined.

Comment: Elaborate your question? What you want to do actually? it's not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to handle this would be have *two separate tables*, and toggle between them when you *edit* a table. So for example we have a table that shows our normal data called `shown` and one with the `input` and `select` for a user to enter data called `edit`. These tables will share the same button, and when clicked it will toggle between the tables, making it look like it's switching between edit and show mode. This way we can just copy the values from the `edit` table to the text in the `shown` table. Here is an example:

```js
$("#edit").hide(); // Hide the edit table first

$("#update").click(function() {
    $("#edit").toggle();
    $("#shown").toggle();
    // If we are going from edit table to shown table
    if($("#shown").is(":visible")) {
        // Get the data from the edit table
        var newSales = $("#edit tr:nth-child(1) td input[name='vouchertype']").val();
        var newPay = $("#edit tr:nth-child(1) td select[name='mode']").val();
        var newTax = $("#edit tr:nth-child(2) td select[name='tax']").val();
        // Then add it to the shown table
        $("#shown tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2)").text(newSales);
        $("#shown tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(3)").text(newPay);
        $("#shown tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(1)").text(newTax);
        $(this).val("Edit");
    }
    else $(this).val("Update");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="shown">
    <tr>
        <td>Sr no</td><td>Sales</td><td>Paid in</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>Taxed</td></tr> 
</table>

<table id="edit">
    <tr>
        <td>Sr no</td><td><input type="text" name="vouchertype" value="Sales" /></td>
    <td>
    <select name="mode">
        <option value="paidin">Paidin</option>
        <option value="paidout">Paidout</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <select name="tax">
            <option value="Taxed">Taxed</option>
            <option value="Not Taxed">Not Taxed</option>
        </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<input id="update" type="submit" name="submit" value="Edit"/>
```

*Notice:* This is an answer to the original question, which is quite different then the new question added in as an edit.

Comment: @KedarB In the selector `#shown tr td:nth-child(2)` to select the nth row ( `tr` ) you would do `:nth-child(n)` on the `tr`. So for example the first row and the second `td` in that row would be: `#shown tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2)`.

Comment: @KedarB You completely changed the HTML structure, have be the same as the original question. For example you removed `name = "vouchertype"` , then clearly when this code attempts to get it: `edit tr:nth-child(1) td input[name='vouchertype']` it will not work since you removed the name in the HTML.

Comment: Sry for that but this is my original code in program..earlier which I posted is just sample code.

Comment: @KedarB Just apply the same idea from your sample code to your real code then.